# Database design for user driven website

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, social-networking

Assuming I want to have a web application that requires storing user information, images, etc as well as storing status updates or posts/comments would I want to separate tables?
For example if I have a "users" table that contains users information like passwords, emails, and typical social networking info like age, location etc. Would it be a good idea do create a second table("posts") that handles user content such as comments and/or post?

Table one: "users"

- UserID
- Username
- Age
- etc.

Table Two: "posts"

- PostID
- PostContent
- PostAuthor
- PostDate
- etc

Is this a valid organization? Furthermore if I wanted to keep track of media should I do this in ANOTHER table?

Table Three: "media"

- ID
- Type
- Uploader
- etc.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm curious to see if I'm on the right track or just completely lost. I am mostly wondering if I should have many tables or if I should have larger less segregated tables.
Also of note thus far I planned on keeping information such as followers(or friends) in the 'users' table but I'm not sure that's a good idea in retrospect.
thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking to design a database you create a table for each object you will be dealing with. In you example you have `Users`, `Posts`, `Comments` and `Media`. From that you can flesh out what it is you want to store for each object. Each item you want to store is a field in the table:

```
[Users]
ID
Username
PasswordHash
Age
Birthdate
Email
JoinDate
LastLogin

[Posts]
ID
UserID
Title
Content
CreateDate
PostedDate

[Comments]
ID
PostID
UserID
Content

[Media]
ID
Title
Description
FileURI
```

Taking a look above you can see a basic structure for holding the information for each object. By the field names you can even tell the relationships between the objects. That is a post has a `UserID` so the post was created by that user. the comments have a `PostID` and a `UserID` so you can see that a comment was written by a person for a specific post.

Once you have the general fields identified you can look at some other aspects of the design. For example right now the `Email` field under the Users table means that a user can have one (1) email address, no more. You can solve this one of two ways... add more email fields (EmailA, EmailB, EmailC) this generally works if you know there are specific types of emails you are dealing with, for example EmailWork or EmailHome. This doesn't work if you do not know how many emails in total there will be. To solve this you can pull the emails out into its own table:

```
[Users]
ID
Username
PasswordHash
Age
Birthdate
JoinDate
LastLogin

[Emails]
ID
UserID
Email
```

Now you can have any number of emails for a single user. You can do this for just about any database you are trying to design. Take it in small steps and break your bigger objects into smaller ones as needed.

*Update*

To deal with friends you should think about the relationship you are dealing with. There is one (1) person with many friends. In relation to the tables above its one User to many Users. This can be done with a special table that hold no information other than the relationship you are looking for.

```
[Friends]
[UserA]
[UserB]
```

So if the current user's ID is in A his friend's ID is in B and visa-verse. This sets up the friendship so that if you are my friend, then I am your friend. There is no way for me to be your friend without you being mine. If you want to setup the ability for one way friendships you can setup the table like this:

```
[Friends]
[UserID]
[FriendID]
```

So If we are both friends with each other there would have to be 2 records, one for my friendship to you and one for your freindship to me.

Comment: Thank you! You've answered my question exactly! I was hoping that organizing this way was correct because it seems so much neater and modular. How would you go about dealing with user relationships such as 'friends' or 'subscribers' or 'followers'? like user1 is friends with user2 and user3

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiple tables.

The amount of tables depends on how complex you want your interactive site to be. Based on what you have posted you would need a table that would store information about the users, a table for comments, and more such as a table to store status types.

For example tbl_Users should store:
1. UserID
2. First Name
3. Last name
4. Email
5. Password (encrypted)
6. Address
7. City
8. State
9. Country
10. Date of Birth
11. UserStatus
12. Etc

This project sounds like it should be using a relational DB that will pull up records, such as comments, by relative userIDs.

This means that you will need a table that stores the following:
1. CommentID (primary key, int, auto-increment)
2. Comment (text)
3. UserID (foreign key, int)

The comment is attached to a user through a foreign key, which is essentially the userId from the tbl_Users table. You would need to combine these tables in an SQL statement with your script to query the information as a single piece of information. See example code

```
$sql_userWall = "SELECT tbl_Users.*, tbl_Comments.*, tbl_userStatus FROM tbl_Users
INNER JOIN tbl_Comments ON tbl_Users.userID = tbl_Comments.userID
INNER JOIN tbl_UserStatus ON tbl_Users.userID = tbl.UserStatus
WHERE tbl_Users.userID = $userID";
```

This statement essentially says get the information of the provided user from the users table and also get all the comments with that has the same userID attached to it, and get the userStatus from the table of user status'.

Therefore you would need a table called tbl_userStatus that held unique statusIDs (primary key, int, auto-incrementing) along with a text (varchar) of a determined length that may say for example "online" or "offline". When you started the write the info out from e record using php, asp or a similar language the table will automatically retrieve the information from tbl_userStatus for you just by using a simple line like

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['userStatus']; ?>
```

No extra work necessary. Most of your project time will be spent developing the DB structure and writing SQL statements that correctly retrieve the info you want for each page.

There are many great YouTube video series that describe relational DBS and drawing entity relational diagrams. This is what you should look into for learning more on creating the tye of project you were describing.

One last note, if you wanted comments to be visible for all members of a group this would describe what is known as a many-to-many relationship which would require additional tables to allow for multiple users to 'own' a relationship to a single table. You could store a single groupID that referred to a table of groups.

tbl_groups
1. GroupID
2. GroupName
3. More group info, etc

And a table of users registered for the group
Tbl_groupMembers
1. membershipCountID (primary key, int, auto-increment)
2. GroupID (foriegn key, int)
3. UserID (foriegn key, int)

This allows users to registrar for a group and inner join them to group based comments. These relationships take a little more time to understand, the videos will help greatly.

I hope this helps, I'll come back and post some YouTube links later that I found helpful learning this stuff.

Comment: Tye subscribing to he following videos:

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to videos

Comment: Try subscribing to the following videos: foxiaacademy - Logical Data Modeling (watch all 5 parts) and kvviswana - Introduction to Entity Relationship Diagrams another 5 part series. By the end of these videos, assuming that you understand everything, you will be able to design more complex databases for web applications. It did take me a few times to fully comprehend everything in the lessons. Good luck, your abilities and applications will improve greatly soon!